# Lubuntu screen goes completely black after 15 minutes

Tags: screen

I just freshly installed Lubuntu 14.04.01 on old laptop and on each fresh reboot after ~15 minutes while doing stuff screen goes completely black with no options on returning to desktop. Notice I am using laptop while this happens (laptop is not idle at all).

I disabled screen saver, and light lock and installed xscreensaver and put

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Screensaver
Type=Applicaton
Exec=xscreensaver -nosplash
```

to `/etc/xdg/autostart/screensaver.desktop`.

but still the same. I am not even sure if that's related to screen saver because it seems to be impossible to leave that black screen (and it happens while I am using computer).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Update: The black screen appears immediately but first 5 seconds or so it's not 100% black and I can barely see the desktop background, but after several more seconds it becomes 100% background. As if someone reduced brightness to 95% and then in 5 seconds to 100%.

Also happens almost instantly when opening youtube video in chrome.

Comment: Try removing xscreensaver from your system. Does that help?

Comment: Removed xscreensaver. Monitored temp, which is always very cool, but still got black screen while using. Also audio still plays while on black screen, but I must reboot cause it's impossible to leave that.

Comment: only happens opening youtube videos in chrome?

Comment: @Xen2050 no, not necessarily. Happens when i only have terminal opened, but  it seems like when launching video it happens more quickly.

Comment: This is *not* a joke: If you shine a flashlight on your screen when it's dark, can you still see your windows reflected?  If yes, your back-light might be dying...